# Error: unknown file System

Tags: windows-10, grub

my system had dual Operating system so Yesterday I deleted my Ubuntu partition, but I restarted it was showing me `Error: Unknown filesystem`.

I went through some solutions I found on youtube including command `ls`, `set boot=..` `set prefix=...` `insmod ...`
I soon found out that I have to make a bootable USB device and should go for repairing my OP. I downloaded windows 10 ISO file and using Rufos I burned into my USB. 
I went through Boot settings and gave the first priority to external devices so that the windows boot file gets run.

But the bootfile is not getting run, and is not loading though it has burned correctly since I checked on other device.

I went through some searches but got confused. Anyone having a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are getting the exact same error whether the usb stick is plugged or not.

Given that the "unknown filesystem" errors means that there is actual access to your internal drive (the filesystem has to be read before it is declared as "unknown"), there is probably something wrong in your boot order. Indeed, if you are booting on the USB stick, only it's bootloader will be executed, and then the system that's on it will take care of getting access to your internal's disk filesystem.

Your computer is probably not even trying to boot on the USB stick. Have you seen it recognized in your BIOS configuration tool at any point?

You probably have several functions that you can enable at startup. One of them would be to select from which device you want to boot, without going through the BIOS configuration. Try to select the USB stick from this menu. If you don;t have such an option, make sure in the boot order of your BIOS configuration tool that the USB stick that you plugged in is listed, then put it on top of your boot order.

Comment: yes sir, i am getting this error in both condition whether i connect my usb or not.
Yes, my computer is not even trying to boot on the USB stick.
No, I don't see any functions that I could choose to do enable or disable...
I have checked multiple time the boot order and the first priority is given to 'External Device' 2nd is given to Internal hard disk drive. I am not able to install new operating system as well.

Comment: i even just tried to go by making a SuperGrub2  which is a tool to fix Grab but unfortunately again the system can't recognize the boot device so that it gets start.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after all the attempt I made to solve this problem I have solved it by :
boot repair disk software . below is the link :
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/

Just make a bootable device of having this software in it, insert to computer, restart it, and follow the rest from the given in the link.

best of luck.